# SAS: How to save a user-defined macro to a user-defined library

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I meet a problem when I use SAS macro to do some jobs.

It seems that the following code

```
%MACRO macro-name;
    macro-text
%MEND macro-name;
```

will always save the macro to the work library. I want to save it to another library, for example "mylib" which already exists.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options: compiled & stored, or autocall. Compiled will inherently result in faster code execution (albeit marginal) than autocall, as autocall macros need to be searched for & compiled when called for the first time in a single SAS session.

---

Autocall is perhaps the easiest :

```
%MACRO MYMACRO ;
  /* do stuff */
%MEND ;
```

Save this as mymacro.sas in a given location (e.g. `C:\SAS\Macros\`)

Then in your code (or preferably `autoexec.sas`) :

```
filename autos "C:\SAS\Macros" ;
options append=sasautos=(autos) mrecall mautosource ;
```

You can then call it as usual

```
%MYMACRO ;
```

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002062214.htm

---

Compiled & Stored :

```
libname maclib "C:\SAS\Macros" ;
options mstored sasmstore=maclib ;

%MACRO MYMACRO / store source ;
  /* do stuff */
%MEND ;
```

Then in your program (or again preferably, `autoexec.sas`)

```
libname maclib "C:\SAS\Macros" ;
options mstored sasmstore=maclib ;
```

Call it as usual

```
%MYMACRO ;
```

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001328775.htm